# Using the name of a select box instead of id or class in an event

Tags: jquery

I am using datatables and i am interested in doing something once the user selects something from the select box.The problem is,the select box in datatables do not have an id so that i could have just done

```
$("#myselectboxid").change(function(){
alert('do foo');
});
```

The html for the said select looks like

```
<select name="example_length" size="1" aria-controls="example">
```

Is there a way i can use `example_length` where id or class are not provided?.

Comment: Have a closer look at jquery attribute selectors (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).
`$('select[name=example_length]')` should work in your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('[name="example_length"]').on("change",function(){});
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dubeynee/cn9Fk/13/)

Answer (score 1):

The generated select box will have the name attribute as this:

```
id_of_your_table + '_length'
```

The code for attaching the event to this select box is inside the function `_fnFeatureHtmlLength ( oSettings )` of jquery.datatables.js
So, either you can add your code there or you can add event like this

```
$("#tableId_length").change(function(){
});
```

where `tableId` is the id of your table

Answer (score 1):

The previous replies are close, but the syntax is a little off.

```
$('[name=test]').change(function(){});
```

Note that the entire selector is wrapped in quotes and that the *name* itself doesn't require its own quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can target the select with the regular DOM method and then wrap it in jQUery, something like this:

```
var jq = $(document.getElementsByName("example_length"));
jq.change(function(){
    alert('foo');
});
```

Note that names might not be unique.